# Replace div class to another class using php or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I want to replace the class in the div from
this

`<div class="producttitle"></div>`

to this
`<div class="producttitle h3"></div>`

The above class is under the main div it has around 5 other classes to it

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 cegg-gridbox">
<div class="cegg-thumb"></div>
<div class="producttitle"><div class="cegg-mb10"></div></div>
<div class="cegg-btn-grid cegg-hidden hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
```

```
const div = document.querySelector('producttitle');
div.classList.replace('producttitle','producttitle h3');
```

```
console.log(document.querySelector('producttitle').classList.value);
// Expected output: multi-class header first title
document.querySelector('producttitle').classList.replace('producttitle', 'producttitle h3')
console.log(document.querySelector('producttitle').classList.value);
// Expected output: multi-class header first bundle
```

I tried both the aboves ones but it's not working, correct me what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: cant you just add the class h3 instead of replacing? since you are not really replacing anything, you are just adding a new class to your existing class

Comment: `it's not working`; howso? Is there an error in the console? I don't think `...classList.value` is valid. I would just use `...classList.add("h3")`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found the solution

```
<h3 class="producttitle">
        <?php if ($merchant = TemplateHelper::getMerhantName($item)): ?>
            <div class="cegg-mb10">
                <small class="text-muted title-case"><?php echo \esc_html($merchant); ?></small>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ($item['rating']): ?>
            <div class="cegg-title-rating">
                <?php TemplateHelper::printRating($item, 'small'); ?>
            </div>
        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php echo \esc_html(TemplateHelper::truncate($item['title'], 80)); ?>
    </h3>
```

From basic paragraph to a wrapped heading h3

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below is a proof-of-concept, basically I added two buttons to test adding or removing the class. For the sake of simplicity I assumed that you want to apply this for a single element, hence the use of `.querySelector`.

```js
function add(selector, cl) {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (element.classList.contains(cl)) {
        alert('Class was already added');
    } else {
        element.classList.add('h3');
    }
}

function remove(selector, cl) {
    let element = document.querySelector(selector);
    if (!element.classList.contains(cl)) {
        alert('Class was already removed');
    } else {
        element.classList.remove('h3');
    }
}
```

```css
.h3 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 cegg-gridbox">
<div class="cegg-thumb"></div>
<div class="producttitle">The title<div class="cegg-mb10"></div></div>
<div class="cegg-btn-grid cegg-hidden hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="add('.producttitle', 'h3')" value="Add h3">
<input type="button" onclick="remove('.producttitle', 'h3')" value="Remove h3">
```

Let's see how we can support plural class additions/removals:

```js
function add(selector, cl) {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (let element of elements) {
        if (!element.classList.contains(cl)) {
            element.classList.add(cl);
        }
    }
}

function remove(selector, cl) {
    let elements = document.querySelectorAll(selector);
    for (let element of elements) {
        if (element.classList.contains(cl)) {
            element.classList.remove('h3');
        }
    }
}
```

```css
.h3 {
    background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 cegg-gridbox">
<div class="cegg-thumb"></div>
<div class="producttitle">The title<div class="cegg-mb10"></div></div>
<div class="cegg-btn-grid cegg-hidden hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 cegg-gridbox">
<div class="cegg-thumb"></div>
<div class="producttitle">The second title<div class="cegg-mb10"></div></div>
<div class="cegg-btn-grid cegg-hidden hidden-xs"></div>
</div>
<input type="button" onclick="add('.producttitle', 'h3')" value="Add h3">
<input type="button" onclick="remove('.producttitle', 'h3')" value="Remove h3">
```

Here I'm not alerting when the addition/removal did not succeed because it does not make sense to alert partial failures in the context of this test.